# Cassandra memory usage

Tags: cassandra-2.0

In Cassandra configuration memory limit is given.Suppose we have physical memory of 8 gb out of which 2 gb is allocated to Cassandra. So if Cassandra's memory usage goes upto 2gb, does additional memory from 8 gb will be allocated to Cassandra or not?